# Compressed chunks: performance and data size

Tags: timescaledb

I'm new to TimescaleDB and started with exploring the documentation. It's pretty clear and looks like I've missed something important.

I've created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE session_created
(
    event_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    client_id integer,
    client_version text,
    identifier text,
    platform text,
    remote_addr text,
    country text,
    type smallint,
    session text
);

CREATE INDEX session_created_client_id_idx ON session_created USING btree (client_id ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX session_created_event_timestamp_idx ON session_created USING btree (event_timestamp ASC NULLS LAST);
```

Then made it a hypertable with following compression settings:

```
SELECT create_hypertable('session_created','event_timestamp');

ALTER TABLE session_created SET (
  timescaledb.compress,
  timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'event_timestamp'
);

SELECT add_compression_policy('session_created', INTERVAL '1 days');
```

And filled the table with one million rows a day from 2021-11-09 to 2021-11-2. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO session_created
(
    event_timestamp,
    client_id,
    client_version,
    identifier,
    platform,
    remote_addr,
    country,
    type,
    session
)
SELECT '2021-11-23 00:00:00'::timestamp + s.id * interval '85 milliseconds', 
    s.id % 500000, 
    '1.0.1234', 
    'deviceid-' || s.id % 500000,
    'Android',
    '127.0.0.' || s.id % 256,
    'RU',
    0,
    md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS s(id);
```

The target table contained three chunks and I've compressed two of them to play with core TimescaleDB feature:

```
SELECT compress_chunk(chunk_name)
FROM show_chunks('session_created', older_than => INTERVAL ' 1 day') chunk_name;
```

The problem is that compressed data took three much space than data before compression.

| before compression | after compression |
| --- | --- |
| 1702 MB | 4178 MB |

Also, it takes more time to query compressed data in an analitic manner:

```
select event_timestamp::date as date, count(distinct client_id) as clients
from session_created
where event_timestamp between (current_date - 7)::date and (current_date - 6)::date - interval '1 second'
group by 1
```

The question is what I've missed in the documentation? What are sources of the problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the "time" column used to create the hypertable is not used as a segment by column while setting up compression.
segment_by column is a column that has some commonality across the data set.
e.g. If we have a table with device readings
(device_id, event_timestamp, event_id, reading)
the segment by column could be device_id (say you have a few 1000 devices and the device_readings table has data in the order of millions/billions).  Note that the data in the segment by column is never stored in compressed form. Only the non segment by columns get compressed.

Comment: Thank's for explanation, I've missed the idea of segmentation. Compression is good enough if `client_id` column is used for segmentation. And queries with `client_id = ?` in where clause works well, but analytic queries like above still shows worse performance